# How to achieve a cm accuracy in GNSS?

Tags: gps

I am currently working on a project about the GNSS precise positioning,
I want to know which modules or materials needed in order to get an accuracy of few centimeters.

Comment: RICS guidelines on using GNSS in surveying and mapping: [link](https://www.rics.org/globalassets/rics-website/media/upholding-professional-standards/sector-standards/land/guidelines-for-the-use-of-gnss-in-surveying-and-mapping-2nd-edition-rics.pdf)

Comment: Some more detail / clarification would help this question.  By "precise positioning", are you referring to "Precise Point Positioning (PPP)" or do you just mean "accurate"?  Every Survey company (Trimble, Leica, Topcon, etc) can supply suitable equipment, but are you looking for a low-cost route?  And how long are you prepared to collect data at a point?  Expecting 3cm accuracy with 10 second occupation is different from 24 hour occupation.

Comment: Yes, I need to 3 cm accuracy within 10 seconds , that kind of job